# Excel - Part of file name from cell

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a way to make something like `='[X"&A1&".xlsx]Z'!$A3`
I have 2 files. File X.xlxs collecting data from multiple files Y.xlxs, files Y.xlxs are named Y1.xlxs, Y2.xlxs, ..., Y1210.xlxs.

I tried `INDIRECT` and `"&&"`.

I'm looking for simple way to get data from specific cell in specific file Y.xlxs.
In file X I puted into cell A1 - An part of filename 1 - n.

Comment: How did you try indirect?

Comment: `=INDIRECT( "'" & A1 & "[" & B1 & "]" & C1 & "'!" & D1)` - I had path to file in A1, File name that was changed by editing another cell, C1 sheet, D1 cell. `="X" &TEXT(G1;0)&".xlsx"`

Comment: If I recall correctly you need to concatenate the strings inside indirect with CONCATENATE()

Comment: any luck on the tries ?

Answer (score 0):

> to get data from specific cell in specific file Y.xlxs

will need : `=INDIRECT("[Y"&A1&".xlsx]Sheet1!$A$3",TRUE)`

just as @Andreas said.

anyway.. a quick reference to indirect() function documentation will help in its understanding.

Please share if it works/not. ( :